# React Table delete row only works once

Tags: reactjs, state, mdbtable

I am using a third party package to build a react table that has a button on each row to give the user the option to remove the row. Currently, it will only remove a row on the first time but will not successfully delete any subsequent rows. On the second press of a delete button, if it had the same index as the previously deleted row (e.g. index 0) then it will not delete, but if it has a different index then the row will delete and the previously deleted row will return. Am I mismanaging the state? Would a timer be beneficial?

Below is my code.

** UsersTable.js **

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { MDBDatatable, MDBBtn, MDBIcon } from 'mdb-react-ui-kit';
import Wrapper from '../Wrapper';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { rows, cols } from '../../variables/Users';

const Table = ({ tableData }) => {
  // const [actionData, setActionData] = useState({
  //   columns: cols,
  //   rows: addCustomButtons(rows)
  // });

  return (
    <StyledTable
      hover
      striped

      data={tableData}
      advancedData
      entriesOptions={[5, 10, 20]}
      entries={10}

      fixedHeader
      maxHeight='460px'
    />
  )
}

export default function UsersTable() {
  const [tableData, setTableData] = useState({
    columns: cols,
    rows: addCustomButtons(rows)
  })

  function addCustomButtons(rows) {
    return rows.map((row, idx) => {
      return {
        ...row,
        index: idx,
        email: (
          <StyledLink
            to='#'
            onClick={(e) => {
              window.location.href = `mailto:${row.emailraw}`;
              e.preventDefault();
            }}
          >
            {row.emailraw}
          </StyledLink>
        ),
        buttons: (
          <>
            <StyledButton
              size='sm'
              floating
              className='message-btn'
              onClick={() => console.log(`send a message to ${row.emailraw}`)}
            >
              <MDBIcon icon='envelope' />
            </StyledButton>
            <StyledButton outline size='sm' floating className='call-btn' onClick={() => console.log(`edit user settings`)}>
              <MDBIcon icon='arrow-right' />
            </StyledButton>
            <StyledButton
              size='sm'
              floating
              className='remove-user-btn'
              onClick={() => deleteRow(idx)}
            >
              <MDBIcon icon="trash" />
            </StyledButton>
          </>
        ),
      };
    })
  }


  // const removeRowHandler = (index) => {
  //   if (tableData.rows.length > 1) {
  //     var updatedRows = [...tableData.rows]
  //     var indexToRemove = updatedRows.findIndex(x => x.index === index)

  //     if (indexToRemove > -1) {
  //       var newRows = [
  //         ...updatedRows.slice(0, indexToRemove),
  //         ...updatedRows.slice(indexToRemove + 1, updatedRows.length)
  //       ]

  //       setTableData({
  //         columns: cols,
  //         rows: newRows
  //       })
  //     }
  //   }
  // }

  const deleteRow = (index) => {
    if (tableData.rows.length > 0) {
      var updatedRows = [...tableData.rows]
      console.log(index, '1st rowData', updatedRows)

      var indexToRemove = updatedRows.findIndex(x => x.index === index)
      console.log('remove', indexToRemove, index)

      if (indexToRemove > -1) {
        updatedRows.splice(indexToRemove, 1)
        var newRows = addCustomButtons(updatedRows)

        console.log(newRows)
        setTableData((prevState) => {
          return {
            ...prevState,
            rows: newRows
          }
        })
      }
    }
  }

  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <TableContainer>
        <Table tableData={tableData} />
      </TableContainer>
    </Wrapper>
  );
}
```

Comment: what do the logs in the deleteRow function say when you click the first time, the second time on the same element, and also the second time on a different element?

Comment: On deleting first row (first time): I get the correct array with the first row (of prior array) missing - on both print statements (even though I expected it to be in first print statement). When I delete the new first row (second time), I get an array of length 7 that is unchanged from the array printed in the first time. I get that for both print statements. The row does NOT delete. On the third time for the (new) third row, when I go to delete, the OLD third row deletes and the first row deleted comes back, again it prints the same array as the first print statement for both print statement

Comment: the problem might be with `onClick={() => deleteRow(idx)}`. i think the index of the array isn't matching to the index in that object. There are a lot of indexes being thrown around, and the line `var indexToRemove = updatedRows.findIndex(x => x.index === index)` is a big code smell. 

To simplify this, make a function that just updates the state. That's your onClick function. Don't call the addCUstomButtons function until you need it. Make addCustomButtons take in the state, not a list of rows. That way the state and addCUstomButtons are decoupled.

I hope that helps!!

Comment: I updated the callback to use `rowData.filter((row) => row.index !== index);` and it properly removes the selected row each time consecutively but after subsequent deletes, the old deleted row returns... I know useState is async - BUT it is never updating the array for the newer shorter array. How does it have access to previous states (other than the immediate precedent state)?